# SQL column type JSON returning invalid characters

Tags: mysql, json

I have created a table on my database with a column type JSON, the problem is that when I get that column values on API, some characters doesnt came correctly.

Example:

I am inserting this values:

```
[
    {
        "nome": "test",
        "email": "test",
    },
    {
        "nome": "André Lopes",
        "email": "andre.lopes@email.pt",
    }
]
```

But when I receive them on API they came

```
[
    {
        "nome": "atemphar", 
        "email": "atemphar"
    },
    {
        "nome": "AndrÃ© Lopes", 
        email": "andre.lopes@email.pt"
    }
]
```

And as you can see the name André, doesnt come with é.

How can I solve this problem, I tried to change collation, but gives me always `is not valid character set 'binary'`

Comment: @JeroenMostert So you are suggesting me to change the type to varchar?

Comment: I actually see I made the assumption that you're using SQL Server, but your question doesn't say that. Are you? Either way, tag your question with the RDBMS you're using, just `sql` is too broad. Ideally, also include the technology/code you're using to insert records, and tag the question with that.

Comment: Sry, I am using SQL Server, on laragon where I use phpMyAdmin to administrate it. There only says that the Server type: MySQL

Comment: Exactly -- so that's *not* Microsoft SQL Server, it's MySQL. My first comment therefore doesn't apply (and I've removed it) and you should tag your question appropriately.

Comment: I already changed it @JeroenMostert Thanks anyways